# C variable declared and assigned to function call

Tags: c

The local variable `btmp` in the below code is declared with an assignment to a function call. That function is reading the value of a register `RegX`. The next line writes to another register `Reg_ADDR`, which is the purpose of these lines of code. The lines thereafter potentially update `btmp`.

As this function does not return anything, is there any purpose to the last 4 lines of code? Or is there something complicated going on, e.g. btmp is some sort of pointer?

```
void SetDeviceAddress( uint8_t address, ENUM_MODE AddressMode)
{   
    uint8_t btmp = DeviceReadReg( RegX ) & ~0x03;
    DeviceWriteReg(Reg_ADDR, address);
    if     ( AddressMode == MODE0 )     {}
    else if( AddressMode == MODE1 )     { btmp |= 0x01; }
    else if( AddressMode == MODE2 )     { btmp |= 0x02; }
    else if( AddressMode == MODE3 )     { btmp |= 0x03; }   
}
```

Comment: I can't see a purpose to those lines.

Comment: It's not a pointer, and even if it were, the code isn't dereferencing it.

Comment: Maybe there used to be more to the function and it was removed, but they left those lines.

Comment: No purpose, maybe some starving code from previous modifications...

Comment: Where is this code coming from? You are correct. All those conditional statements modify btmp which is just a local variable. uint8_t is a type defined in stdint.h. But, declaring a uint8_t variable isn't any different than if you were to declare an int or double local to that function. So, all you're doing is modifying a local variable which is pointless.

Comment: Rather strange that neither `btmp` nor `AddressMode` are used. Wonder if that's original code, or maybe post-processed to remove some debug/logging.

Comment: btmp has a local scope, it's not a pointer variable, the last 4 lines seems just modifying btmp and in the end when the control returns from the function, the current method's stack is unwind, therefore making changes to btmp useless

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I suspect the code has evolved over time but am not sure. Good to get my understanding confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

The 'btmp' variable is the local variable, so any write/change operations related to this are lost while clearing the stack on function return. Moreover, it seems that the first line of this code is useless too - as long as the DeviceReadReg() call has no side effects (if it has, this is really bad coding practice).
So, the real equivalent of the function is:

```
void SetDeviceAddress(uint8_t address, ENUM_MODE AddressMode)
{   
    DeviceWriteReg(Reg_ADDR, address);
}
```

or better:

```
void SetDeviceAddress(uint8_t address)
{   
    DeviceWriteReg(Reg_ADDR, address);
}
```